# gluon mobile iOS app - unable to upload ipa to App Store Connect

Tags: ios, upload, ipa, gluon-mobile

I am trying to upload an iOS app to App Store Connect using Transporter. When I try to deliver the ipa to App Store Connect from Transporter, the delivery fails with the following message:

"Asset validation failed (90034)
Missing or invalid signature. The bundle 'com.****.****' at bundle path 'Payload/****.app' is not signed using an Apple submission certificate. (ID: 8da30872-073a-4f2a-b51f-29b0c920be16)"

I have created a distribution signing certificate and provisioning profile following the gluon documentation (https://docs.gluonhq.com/#platforms_ios_distribution). That seems to have been completed without a problem.

I have added a  section in my POM as shown below:

```
<groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
                <artifactId>gluonfx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${gluonfx.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!--suppress UnresolvedMavenProperty -->
                    <target>${gluonfx.target}</target>
                    <appIdentifier>com.maplesunbook.DateCon</appIdentifier>
                    <attachList>
                        <list>display</list>
                        <list>lifecycle</list>
                        <list>statusbar</list>
                        <list>storage</list>
                    </attachList>
                    <reflectionList>
                        <list>com.maplesunbook.views.ConverterPresenter</list>
                        <list>com.maplesunbook.views.CalculatorPresenter</list>
                        <list>com.maplesunbook.views.SettingsPresenter</list>
                        <list>javafx.scene.control.DatePicker</list>
                    </reflectionList>
                    <bundlesList>
                        <list>lang_en</list>
                        <list>lang_ja</list>
                    </bundlesList>
                    <nativeImageArgs>
                        <arg>-H:IncludeLocales=en,ja</arg> <!--// your list of locales-->
                        <!-- <arg>-H:+IncludeAllLocales</arg>  // all possible locales, but bigger size-->
                    </nativeImageArgs>
                    <graalvmHome>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/graalvm-svm-java17-darwin-gluon-22.1.0.1-Final/Contents/Home</graalvmHome>
                    <mainClass>${mainClassName}</mainClass>
                    <releaseConfiguration>
                        <bundleVersion>1</bundleVersion>
                        <bundleShortVersion>1.0</bundleShortVersion>
                        <providedSigningIdentity>iPhone Distribution: ****** (*******)</providedSigningIdentity>
                        <providedProvisioningProfile>Date Converter Profile</providedProvisioningProfile>
                    </releaseConfiguration>
                </configuration>
```

I have double-checked the signing certificate details (shown above as **** for privacy), and mvn -Pios gluonfx:build and :package both execute without error.

As far as I can tell there should be no signing issues, unless there is another step that I am missing somewhere.

Alternatively, is there another preferred method for delivering the ipa to App Store Connect?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is (I believe) the relevant portion of the log file (client-debug0.log):

```
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:50 JST 2023][FINE] Got Bundle ID = com.maplesunbook.DateCon
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:50 JST 2023][FINE] PB Command for security: security find-identity -p codesigning -v
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:50 JST 2023][FINE] Start process security...
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:51 JST 2023][FINE] [SUB]   1) E2550840E24A1B32716F4CA6FBCF7085F729EDA2 "Apple Development: shoun.sariban29@ezweb.ne.jp (9X9SSQ78D3)"
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:51 JST 2023][FINE] [SUB]   2) ABF0F342C8207D2472B315604C8557B048789EFC "Apple Development: maplesunbook@gmail.com (V644TYZABW)"
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:51 JST 2023][FINE] [SUB]   3) 246FD6FE0D14A4C39BCD5A83E28DC6B62439265D "iPhone Distribution: Sean Albert Sullivan (96TA5FQVN8)"
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:51 JST 2023][FINE] [SUB]      3 valid identities found
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:51 JST 2023][FINE] Result for security: 0
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:51 JST 2023][FINE] Mobile provision asked with bundleId = com.maplesunbook.DateCon (initial bundleId: com.maplesunbook.DateCon)
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:51 JST 2023][FINE] Mobile provisioning profile for /Users/sion/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/997a5862-fbf9-4053-ab13-9f832ebf8b0e.mobileprovision
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:51 JST 2023][FINE] Checking mobile provision Date Converter
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:51 JST 2023][FINE] DateConPP matches SigningIdentity{name='iPhone Distribution: Sean Albert Sullivan (96TA5FQVN8)', sha1='246FD6FE0D14A4C39BCD5A83E28DC6B62439265D'}
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:51 JST 2023][FINE] Got provisioning profile: DateConPP
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:51 JST 2023][FINE] Entitlements.plist = [com.apple.developer.storekit.external-link.account=com.dd.plist.NSArray@60696365, com.apple.developer.storekit.external-purchase=com.dd.plist.NSArray@60696365, com.apple.developer.storekit.external-purchase-link=com.dd.plist.NSArray@60696365, beta-reports-active=true, application-identifier=96TA5FQVN8.com.maplesunbook.DateCon, keychain-access-groups=com.dd.plist.NSArray@d86f8da2, get-task-allow=false, com.apple.developer.team-identifier=96TA5FQVN8]
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:51 JST 2023][FINE] Signing with entitlements path: /Users/sion/IdeaProjects/DateCon/target/gluonfx/arm64-ios/gvm/tmp/Entitlements.plist
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:51 JST 2023][FINE] Signing app with identity: SigningIdentity{name='iPhone Distribution: Sean Albert Sullivan (96TA5FQVN8)', sha1='246FD6FE0D14A4C39BCD5A83E28DC6B62439265D'}
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:51 JST 2023][FINE] PB Command for xcrun: xcrun -sdk iphoneos -f codesign_allocate
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:51 JST 2023][FINE] Start process xcrun...
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:51 JST 2023][FINE] [SUB] /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:51 JST 2023][FINE] Result for xcrun: 0
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:51 JST 2023][FINE] PB Command for codesign: codesign --generate-entitlement-der --force --sign 246FD6FE0D14A4C39BCD5A83E28DC6B62439265D --entitlements /Users/sion/IdeaProjects/DateCon/target/gluonfx/arm64-ios/gvm/tmp/Entitlements.plist /Users/sion/IdeaProjects/DateCon/target/gluonfx/arm64-ios/Date Converter.app
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:51 JST 2023][FINE] Start process codesign...
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:52 JST 2023][FINE] Result for codesign: true
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:52 JST 2023][FINE] Validating codesign...
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:52 JST 2023][FINE] PB Command for verify: codesign --verify -vvvv /Users/sion/IdeaProjects/DateCon/target/gluonfx/arm64-ios/Date Converter.app
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:52 JST 2023][FINE] Start process verify...
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:52 JST 2023][FINE] [SUB] /Users/sion/IdeaProjects/DateCon/target/gluonfx/arm64-ios/Date Converter.app: valid on disk
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:52 JST 2023][FINE] [SUB] /Users/sion/IdeaProjects/DateCon/target/gluonfx/arm64-ios/Date Converter.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:52 JST 2023][FINE] Result for verify: true
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:52 JST 2023][FINE] Signing done successfully
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:52 JST 2023][INFO] The .app bundle was created successfully at: /Users/sion/IdeaProjects/DateCon/target/gluonfx/arm64-ios/Date Converter.app
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:52 JST 2023][INFO] Building .ipa for /Users/sion/IdeaProjects/DateCon/target/gluonfx/arm64-ios/Date Converter.app
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:52 JST 2023][FINE] PB Command for cp: cp -Rp /Users/sion/IdeaProjects/DateCon/target/gluonfx/arm64-ios/Date Converter.app /Users/sion/IdeaProjects/DateCon/target/gluonfx/arm64-ios/gvm/tmp/tmpApp/Payload
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:52 JST 2023][FINE] Start process cp...
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:52 JST 2023][FINE] Result for cp: 0
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:52 JST 2023][FINE] PB Command for zip: zip --symlinks --recurse-paths /Users/sion/IdeaProjects/DateCon/target/gluonfx/arm64-ios/Date Converter.ipa .
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:52 JST 2023][FINE] Start process zip...
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:52 JST 2023][FINE] [SUB] updating: Payload/ (stored 0%)
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:52 JST 2023][FINE] [SUB] updating: Payload/Date Converter.app/ (stored 0%)
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:52 JST 2023][FINE] [SUB] updating: Payload/Date Converter.app/_CodeSignature/ (stored 0%)
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:52 JST 2023][FINE] [SUB] updating: Payload/Date Converter.app/_CodeSignature/CodeResources (deflated 71%)
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:52 JST 2023][FINE] [SUB] updating: Payload/Date Converter.app/.DS_Store (deflated 93%)
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:55 JST 2023][FINE] [SUB] updating: Payload/Date Converter.app/Date Converter (deflated 65%)
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:55 JST 2023][FINE] [SUB] updating: Payload/Date Converter.app/AppIcon60x60@2x.png (deflated 1%)
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:55 JST 2023][FINE] [SUB] updating: Payload/Date Converter.app/Default-Info.plist (deflated 66%)
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:55 JST 2023][FINE] [SUB] updating: Payload/Date Converter.app/Base.lproj/ (stored 0%)
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:55 JST 2023][FINE] [SUB] updating: Payload/Date Converter.app/Base.lproj/LaunchScreen.storyboardc/ (stored 0%)
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:55 JST 2023][FINE] [SUB] updating: Payload/Date Converter.app/Base.lproj/LaunchScreen.storyboardc/01J-lp-oVM-view-Ze5-6b-2t3.nib (deflated 46%)
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:55 JST 2023][FINE] [SUB] updating: Payload/Date Converter.app/Base.lproj/LaunchScreen.storyboardc/UIViewController-01J-lp-oVM.nib (deflated 34%)
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:55 JST 2023][FINE] [SUB] updating: Payload/Date Converter.app/Base.lproj/LaunchScreen.storyboardc/Info.plist (deflated 42%)
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:55 JST 2023][FINE] [SUB] updating: Payload/Date Converter.app/Base.lproj/MainScreen.storyboardc/ (stored 0%)
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:55 JST 2023][FINE] [SUB] updating: Payload/Date Converter.app/Base.lproj/MainScreen.storyboardc/UIViewController-BYZ-38-t0r.nib (deflated 34%)
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:55 JST 2023][FINE] [SUB] updating: Payload/Date Converter.app/Base.lproj/MainScreen.storyboardc/BYZ-38-t0r-view-8bC-Xf-vdC.nib (deflated 38%)
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:55 JST 2023][FINE] [SUB] updating: Payload/Date Converter.app/Base.lproj/MainScreen.storyboardc/Info.plist (deflated 42%)
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:55 JST 2023][FINE] [SUB] updating: Payload/Date Converter.app/Assets.car (deflated 12%)
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:55 JST 2023][FINE] [SUB] updating: Payload/Date Converter.app/AppIcon76x76@2x~ipad.png (deflated 1%)
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:55 JST 2023][FINE] [SUB] updating: Payload/Date Converter.app/embedded.mobileprovision (deflated 36%)
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:55 JST 2023][FINE] [SUB] updating: Payload/Date Converter.app/Info.plist (deflated 32%)
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:55 JST 2023][FINE] [SUB] updating: Payload/Date Converter.app/calendar-round-con813.png (deflated 4%)
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:55 JST 2023][FINE] Result for zip: 0
[Fri Mar 17 11:07:55 JST 2023][INFO] The .ipa bundle was created successfully at: /Users/sion/IdeaProjects/DateCon/target/gluonfx/arm64-ios/Date Converter.ipa
```

Comment: Check the logs for the `gluonfx:package` goal, there you will see if the app was signed successfully or not. As a quick test, if your iPhone certificate is properly installed, you might want to try packaging again _without_ `providedSigningIdentity` and `providedProvisioningProfile` in your pom, so just comment them out and try again?

Comment: @JoséPereda Thank you for your help. I checked the "client-debug0.log" file and it seems to indicate that the app was signed successfully. The app identifier includes in-app purchase capabilities, and so I am wondering if it is an issue with entitlements. However, I am not sure which key or keys to include in the Entitlements.plist file to cover this capability. As always, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hard to say without looking at the logs, but just make sure the identity and prov. profile match exactly the distribution ones and these are valid (i.e. not expired). Check `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles` for all the prov. profiles that might collide somehow. Also run from terminal: `codesign -vvvv *.app`, see that everything looks good.

Comment: @JoséPereda I have edited my question to include the relevant portion of the log file. As far as I can tell, it seems as though the signing is completing successfully. I checked the things you mentioned in your last comment, but everything seems to check out. I double-checked the App ID, distribution certificate, and provisioning profile. I ran codesign -vvvv *.app from the terminal, and had the following output: "Date Converter.app: valid on disk
Date Converter.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement". But I still get the same error "Missing or invalid signature" in Transporter.

Comment: @JoséPereda Thank you for your suggestions. After re-creating the signing certificate and changing it to an Apple Distribution (instead of IOS Distribution) certificate,  re-generating the provisioning profile, deleting all previous certificates and provisioning profiles, and doing a clean build, I was finally able to upload the ipa without error.